# Difference between "public bool xy" and "public bool xy { get; set; }

Tags: c#

I am quite new to C# and this is a concept I still am not able to understand.

If I set a bool to be public I can write onto it, and read from it. Why then is it necessary to add `{get; set;}` to it?

Comment: One is a field, the other is a property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c try that

Comment: I guess that helped me out! I didnt know the words "field" and "property". Now I do, thanks!